# Combine 2 Mysql queries in to 1 (efficient way)

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, multiple-tables

I have 2 tables:

1. The first contains data for the current day (per hour) - this table has raw data, that needs to be processed.
2. The second contains data for previous day (per day) - this table already has the values calculated for every day.

I want to combine this to rows in a MySQL query, so that I return the data for previous dates (per day) and for current day (again, per day).

Currently I am using 2 mysql queries:

```
//table 1, data for current day
                    $qry1="
            select DATE_FORMAT(completedate,'%Y-%m-%d') as date, SUM(IF(complete = 1,affpayout,0)) as pay, COUNT(*) as leads
            from leads
            where affiliateid={$_SESSION["id"]}  AND completedate>'$date' 
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(completedate,'%Y-%m-%d')";
//table 2, data for previous days, already processsed, we just need to select it
            $qry2="
            select DATE(date) as date, affrevenue as pay, totalleads as leads
            from leadsdays
            GROUP BY DATE(date)";
```

How can I combine the 2 efficiently (speed performance is an issue)? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `UNION`. Also, make sure your tables are indexed properly. Looks like you'll want `completedate` and `affiliateid` indexed at least. Not sure how much more efficient two queries is versus one union though...

```
$qry = "(select 
    DATE_FORMAT(completedate,'%Y-%m-%d') as `date`, 
    SUM(IF(complete = 1,affpayout,0)) as pay, 
    COUNT(*) as leads
    from leads
    where affiliateid={$_SESSION["id"]}  AND completedate>'$date' 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(completedate,'%Y-%m-%d')) 
    UNION 
    (select 
    DATE(`date`) as `date`, 
    affrevenue as pay, 
    totalleads as leads
    from leadsdays
    GROUP BY DATE(`date`)) 
    ORDER BY DATE(`date`)";
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I did some tests and in my case it's faster to use union instead of 2 queries. Merry Christmas :) !